# Define GRASS region to desaggregated DEM raster with rgrass7

Tags: raster, r, spatial-analyst, resolution, rgrass7

I want to define my Grass region with `g.region` and my raster to desaggregated this raster. I have error with `g.region` function when I try this :

```
#Create environment  
initGRASS("C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.6",
          override = TRUE,
          gisDbase = "GRASS_TEMP",
          home = setwd(WD),
          mapset = "PERMANENT",
          remove_GISRC = TRUE)

# Modify projection
execGRASS("g.proj", flags = "c", epsg = 2975)

#Load DEM in Grass
execGRASS("r.in.gdal",
          flags = "overwrite",
          parameters = list(input = paste(getwd(), "/Dalles_MNT/Dalles_fusionnees/MNT_2_dalles_test.tif",  sep=""), 
                            output = "GRASS_raster"))

# Define the Grass region with my raster
execGRASS("g.region", raster = paste(getwd(), "/Dalles_MNT/Dalles_fusionnees/MNT_2_dalles_test.tif",  sep=""))
execGRASS("g.region", res = "0.25") #change the resolution of my region

# Desaggregated DEM
execGRASS(cmd = "r.resamp.interp",
          flag = "overwrite",
          parameters = list(input = "GRASS_raster", output="MNT_desag_RGRASS", method = "bilinear"))

# Export my raster in .tif
execGRASS(cmd = "r.out.gdal",
          flag = "overwrite",
          parameters = list(input = "MNT_desag_RGRASS",
                            output = paste(getwd(),"/Output_data/MNT_disaggregate_GRASS.tif", sep=""),
                            format = "GTiff"))
```

I have error in this part of my code :

```
> execGRASS("g.region", raster = paste(getwd(), "/Dalles_MNT/Dalles_fusionnees/MNT_2_dalles_test.tif",  sep=""))

ATTENTION: Nom de fichier
           <F:/PTENIG_PY_R/PTENIG_R/Dalles_MNT/Dalles_fusionnees/MNT_2_dalles_test.tif>
           non autorisé. Caractère </> interdit.
ERREUR :Carte raster
        <F:/PTENIG_PY_R/PTENIG_R/Dalles_MNT/Dalles_fusionnees/MNT_2_dalles_test.tif>
        non trouvée
```

I try this :

```
> execGRASS("g.region", raster = "MNT_2_dalles_test.tif")

ERREUR :Carte raster <MNT_2_dalles_test.tif> non trouvée
```

And at final of my code, my raster exported haven't values certainly in relation to this function `g.region`.

My file `MNT_2_dalles_test.tif` exist, I can open it with QGIS without problem, and its path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, it's a object problem ! If some people are interested by this code see below

```
execGRASS("g.region", raster = "GRASS_raster")
```